# How to configure mail().php, so I can use it with the gmail SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp

```
define('SITE_EMAIL', 'example@mydomain.la');

$to1= SITE_EMAIL;
$subject1 = "Contacto Web";
$message1 = 'Hi!';
$headers1  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers1 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers1 .= "From: ".$_POST['name']." <".$_POST['email'].">\r\n";

mail($to1, $subject1, $message1, $headers1);
print "message send!";
```

I'm using this code to send an email from a contact form. But mostly goes to spam or even the mail is not sent. What they recommended was to validate the header. The form and the php file is in my domain but I use google apps, so I think I have to use the google smtp. But I really don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to use mail() with gmail.

Give [phpmailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) a try.

This is a sample of using it with gmail:

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```